# Solving $-1=e^a-2e^{av}$ as part of an equation system

Tags: arithmetic, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, transcendental-equations

## Problem

Given $f_2(x)=e^{ax-b}+c$ with $x \in \left(0,1\right)$, I am trying to calculate the parameters $a,b,c$ in respect to the following constraints:

$$
\begin{align}
  f_2(0) &= 0 \\
  f_2(1) &= 1 \\
  f_2(v) &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
$$
Where $v \in \left(0.5,1\right)$ is a fixed parameter.

## Current Situation

I have tried solving this analytically and have reached several other representations, including $-1=e^a-2e^{av}$, which should lead to a solution for $a$ but have not found one.
Wolfram-alpha can calculate one and given $v=0.6$ as an example, a solution is $a \approx 0.822163$, $b \approx 0.24373$, $c \approx -0.784057$ (see graph below).

Substitution of $e^a=u$ yields $-1 = u - 2u^v$ which seems doable ($v$ is constant), but I can't seem to find a solution myself.

## Question

I would like to hear pointers as to how (and if) this can be solved analytically.

## Context

I am trying to find a monotonic and continuous function $f$ that satisfies the above constraints in order to stretch the interval $\left(0,1\right)$ to have it's new center at $v$.
Such a function exists for the case $v \in \left(0,0.5\right)$ using the logarithm:

$$f_1(x) = a \cdot \ln(x+b)+c$$

The parameters can be determined analytically and given that $\exp$ is the inverse of $\ln$, I expect a similiar solution for $v > 0.5$ using $\exp$.

[image: Graph showing f1 with v=0.1 and f2 with v=0.6]

Comment: (+1) If this is your first question, I applaud the level of detail you've put in. This should be an example for most new users to follow.

Comment: Absolutely. Good detail +1

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution written in terms of Lambert-Tsallis function. This function is defined as a solution of

$ W_q(x) \cdot \bigg( 1 + (1-q)\cdot W_q(x)\bigg)^{\frac{1}{1-q}} = x$

It does not use series expansion neither has convergence problem because it is exact.

$a=\frac{1}{\nu \cdot r} \cdot log\bigg( -\frac{2}{r} \cdot W_{\frac{r-1}{r}}\left( -\frac{r}{2} \cdot 2^{-r}\right) \bigg)$

with $r=\frac{1-\nu}{\nu}$

Following you have a table with $\nu, W_q(x) $ and $a$

\begin{bmatrix}
\nu & W_q(x) & a\\
0.5 & -5.000000e-01 & -1.735079e-11 \\
0.6 & -4.631302e-01 & 8.221632e-01 \\
0.7 & -3.678340e-01 & 1.801072e+00 \\
0.8 & -2.409452e-01 & 3.281280e+00 \\
0.9 & -5.555556e-02 & -6.661338e-15 
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Is there a good reference for this function?

Comment: Such function was first suggested by R V Ramos at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2019.03.046

At his profile or mine at scholar google (k z nobrega) you have a list with applications of the function. We are writing an article with full description of the general characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you are looking for the inverse function of
$$v=\frac 1 a \log \left(\frac{e^a+1}{2}\right)\tag 1$$ with $a \in (0,\infty)$.

As you supposed, it does not exist. From a numerical point of view, there is no difficulties.

Using series, we have
$$\color{red}{w}=2v-1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n \, a^{2n+1}$$ which can be transformed into a $[2p+1,2p]$ Padé approximant $P_p$. For example, the simplest
$$P_2=\frac{3 a \left(a^2+40\right)}{32 \left(a^2+15\right)}$$ whose error is $\frac{31 a^7}{4838400}$.

It is quite decent for $0 \leq a < \frac 52 $ that is to say $\frac 12 \leq v \leq \frac{3}{4}$.

Solving for $a$, we need the solution of the cubic equation
$$3a^3-32w\,a^2+120\,a-480w=0$$ which has only one real root for $v \in [0.5,1.0]$.

$$a=\frac{4}{9} \left(8w+\sqrt{270-256 w^2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 w \left(2048 w^2+405\right)}{\left(270-256
   w^2\right)^{3/2}}\right)\right)\right)$$

Plugging this expression in $(1)$, we have, using Taylor expansion,
$$v=v-\frac{31744 }{4725}\left(v-\frac{1}{2}\right)^7+O\left(\left(v-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{9}\right)$$ For $v=\frac 56$, the error term is $-0.00307$.

Some values

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
v & \text{estimate}& \text{solution} \\
 0.500 & 0.00000 &  0.00000 \\
 0.525 & 0.20033 &  0.20033 \\
 0.550 & 0.40269 &  0.40269 \\
 0.575 & 0.60919 &  0.60919 \\
 0.600 & 0.82216 &  0.82216 \\
 0.625 & 1.04423 &  1.04426 \\
 0.650 & 1.27852 &  1.27865 \\
 0.675 & 1.52881 &  1.52925 \\
 0.700 & 1.79977 &  1.80107 \\
 0.725 & 2.09719 &  2.10077 \\
 0.750 & 2.42824 &  2.43751 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, for large values of $a$, we can write
$$v=1-\frac{\log (2)}{a}+\frac{e^{-a}}{a}+\cdots$$ which leads to
$$a=\frac{\log (2)}{1-v}+W\left(-\frac{2^{-\frac{1}{1-v}}}{1-v}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
v & \text{estimate}& \text{solution} \\
 0.750 & 2.41519 &  2.43751 \\
 0.775 & 2.81420 &  2.82444 \\
 0.800 & 3.27704 &  3.28128 \\
 0.825 & 3.83774 &  3.83923 \\
 0.850 & 4.55057 &  4.55097 \\
 0.875 & 5.51290 &  5.51297 \\
 0.900 & 6.92161 &  6.92161 \\
 0.925 & 9.24067 &  9.24067 \\
 0.950 & 13.8629 &  13.8629 \\
 0.975 & 27.7259 &  27.7259
\end{array}
\right)$$

Trying to improve for values of $v$ around $\frac 34$, we can write
$$\color{red}{x}=v-\frac{2}{5} \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+e^{5/2}\right)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n \, \left(a-\frac{5}{2}\right)^n$$ and build the simplest $[1,1]$ corresponding Padé approximant. The $\beta_n$ being quite messy, they have been rationalized to give for the rhs

$$x=\frac {\left(a-\frac{5}{2}\right) }{\frac{8912 }{3127}\left(a-\frac{5}{2}\right)+\frac{12114}{823}} \implies   a=\frac{5}{2}-\frac{37880478 x}{823 (8912 x-3127)}$$

Using the exact expansion, much better results for the "critical" zone
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
v & \text{estimate}& \text{solution} \\
 0.70 & 1.80789 &  1.80107 \\
 0.71 & 1.92107 &  1.91716 \\
 0.72 & 2.04012 &  2.03821 \\
 0.73 & 2.16553 &  2.16480 \\
 0.74 & 2.29780 &  2.29764 \\
 0.75 & 2.43752 &  2.43751 \\
 0.76 & 2.58533 &  2.58534 \\
 0.77 & 2.74197 &  2.74222 \\
 0.78 & 2.90824 &  2.90943 \\
 0.79 & 3.08506 &  3.0885 \\
 0.80 & 3.27346 &  3.28128
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

$$f_2(x)=e^{ax-b}+c$$

Your constraints yield the equation system

$$\left\{e^{-b}+c=0,e^{a-b}+c=1,e^{av-b}+c=\frac{1}{2}\right\}.$$

This equation system has solutions if

$$b=\ln(e^{a}-1)+2k_1\pi i\ \land\ c=-(e^a-1)^{-1}\ \land\ v=\frac{1}{a}\left(\ln(\frac{1}{2}e^a+\frac{1}{2})+2k_2\pi i\right)$$

for $k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**2)**

$$-1=e^a-2e^{av}$$

$$-1=u-2u^v$$

For rational $v$, this equation is related to an algebraic equation and we can use the known solution formulas and methods for algebraic equations.
For rational $v\neq 0,1$, the equation is related to a [trinomial equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial).
For real or complex $v\neq 0,1$, the equation is in a form similar to a trinomial equation. A closed-form solution can be obtained using confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ therefore.
$\ $

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)